# Incompatible packages in R

Tags: r, package

Working with time series in R, I find out that unfortunately, two packages seem to be incompatible with each other. These are forecast and TSA.

The first snippet shows forecast working as it should.

```
require(forecast)
test<-ts(rnorm(100), frequency=12, start=c(2000,1))
mod<-arima(test, order=c(1,1,2))
mod2<-forecast.Arima(mod, h=12)
```

This MRE shows my problem:

```
require(forecast)
require(TSA)
test<-ts(rnorm(100), frequency=12, start=c(2000,1))
mod<-arima(test, order=c(1,1,2))
mod2<-forecast.Arima(mod, h=12)
```

This is the error:

```
 Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations
```

What can be done in order to make both work (as I seem to need both), or what other packages could I use to work around this problem? I prioritize having forecast work over TSA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `arima` from `TSA` masks `stats::arima`, which is the one that works with `forecast.Arima`. So to get your snippet to work,

```
library(forecast)
library(TSA)
test<-ts(rnorm(100), frequency=12, start=c(2000,1))
mod<-stats::arima(test, order=c(1,1,2)) # Use arima from stats package
mod2<-forecast.Arima(mod, h=12)
```

Make sure to check the conflicts between packages when you load them!